# How to reset a preference to its default value in Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have an extension that allows users to change some default settings of Firefox (e.g. homepage, search engine). I do so by changing the values of some preferences (e.g. `browser.startup.homepage`, `browser.search.defaultEngineName`).

I try to reset the default values of these settings when the user uninstalls the extension. Right now I do so by remembering the original values and setting them back on uninstall. But I wonder, if there is an easier solution to this.

Is it possible to reset the preference to it's original value before remembering it first?

There are methods to get and set the values. But I couldn't find a method to reset or to retrieve the default value of a preference. Is there any such method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always [reset the preference to the application default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPrefBranch#clearUserPref%28%29):

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.prefs.clearUserPref("browser.startup.homepage");
```

For reference: [Services.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm)

However, this will always reset the homepage to `about:home` for example - if the user customized the homepage then that change will be lost which is likely not desirable in your case. And there is no built-in functionality to "reset preference to the value that it had before my extension was installed", you have to save the value yourself.